# ASP.NET Core System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\..." is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to ASP.NET Core so I am playing around with making an API. I am trying to upload a picture through my Web API. The picture is to be saved onto the web server. I am running the API on a Windows Server 2016 Standard Edition VPS Machine. I have IIS 10 installed on the machine. The error I get back (when remote debugging):

> {System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\HomeNET\Houses\13' is denied.
>      at System.IO.Win32FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, FileStream parent)
>      at System.IO.Win32FileSystem.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, FileStream parent)
>      at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
>      at HomeNetAPI.Controllers.HouseController.d__6.MoveNext() in C:\Users\okuhl\Documents\HomeNet\Web API\HomeNetAPI\src\HomeNetAPI\Controllers\HouseController.cs:line 83}

This is weird because directories are created, should they not exist. Here is some of the code, where the fail happens:

```
if (resultHouse != null)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists($"C:/HomeNET/Houses/{resultHouse.HouseID}"))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory($"C:/HomeNET/Houses/{resultHouse.HouseID}");
    }

    String fileName = new FileInfo(imageFile.FileName).Name;
    String fileExtension = new FileInfo(imageFile.FileName).Extension;
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream($"C:/HomeNET/Houses/{resultHouse.HouseID}", 
        FileMode.Create)) //Bombs out after this line
    {
        var result = imageFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        if (result.IsCompleted)
        {
            newHouse.HouseImage = Path.Combine($"C:/HomeNET/Houses/{resultHouse.HouseID}", $".{fileExtension}");
            var updateResult = await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return houseRepository.UpdateHouse(newHouse);
            });
            if (updateResult != null)
            {
                response.DidError = false;
                response.Message = $"House {newHouse.Name} has been created successfully! Invite friends ad family to your house!";
                response.Model = newHouse;
                return Ok(response);
            }
            else
            {
                response.DidError = true;
                response.Message = "Something went wrong with creating the house. Please try again";
                response.Model = newHouse;
                return BadRequest(response);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            response.DidError = true;
            response.Message = $"Something Went wrong with creating your house. House image could not be saved onto the system. \n {result.Exception.Message}";
            response.Model = newHouse;
            return BadRequest(response);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried making the folder available to everyone and that didn't work. I also tried giving my AppPool permission to modify the folder and that didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

In my case (IIS 8.5), I had to add the `IIS_IUSRS` to the application folder to resolve this issue

Comment: this saves my day. I was thinking of NetworkService user. but IIS_IUSRS is the one(when you choose to use the application pool identity.

Comment: Give write and read both access, so upload and download both can work.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking the user that is running the application pool (instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities).

If that user doesn't have access to the C drive, the write will fail.

(Also: try not to code the path again and again in your code. Declare `C:/HomeNET/Houses/` as a const and refer to it that way, or better still, read it from the web.config)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a virtual directory.  Here's how to do it in IIS 7: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771804(v=ws.10).aspx .  For IIS 10 it's probably similar.

Answer (score 0):

Provide permission to Network Service for your Folder/File which is being used by Service

*rightclick your folder -> poperty's -> security ->Edit -> add -> type :NETWORK SERVICE -> check box full control allow-> press ok or apply*

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post as I had hit the error on my FileUpload logic too. However I  am running the code in development under IISExpress. I had started the code with taking the IWebHostEnvironment variables and assigning it to a variable in the Controller class in the Constructor - and then read something that made me think it should be from Appdomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory - which was the root of how I got the error - the source of the BaseDirectory info was fairly dated - my fault in going there - the webHostEnvironment is really the source that I needed.

I used the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("uploadDirName",path) - so that I could pull that back in when the file post actually occurs (session state ideas). Then there were no file exceptions for permissions after using this approach.

```
path = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "UploadedFiles");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("UploadPath", path);
```

and in the POST logic pull that back in

```
path = Path.Combine(
         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("UploadPath").ToString(), file.FileName); 
     using (var stream = new FileStream(path,
                    FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    }
```

Another option for getting the data passed around would have been Session data - but this option was convenient and did job for now.

There was an implication that a separate directory was going to be needed in the question- that type of issue - is a security issue that I have found is needing the service account of app-pool has to be given Modify rights to the folder. That may come later as the development changes over time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to creating a file, but I forgot to include the file name and file extension.